# How to remove [WIP] work in progress tag from pull request on github?

Tags: github, pull-request

I have made a pull request yesterday with the [WIP] tag and now my task is finished, I want the review so how will I remove that WIP tag from the Pull request to make that review ready from the organization repository on GitHub?

Comment: Can someone tell me the steps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to click edit on the right of the PR when you open it, and then you can change the name, else the reviewer when merging into the main branch can change the name, and i suggest to use the git naming convention, to have a clean and organized history, using also [gitmojis](https://gitmoji.dev/)